# .NET 6 app fails to start because wrong SDK version on server

Tags: .net, .net-core

In various applications, I keep running into an issue where the app fails to start because the server it's on has the wrong minor version of .NET 6 SDK installed. Nothing in the source code is explicitly referencing a minor version of the SDK; the project files just say `<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>`. Why is this happening? How can I prevent this kind of broken deployment if there is nothing in source that corresponds to it?

```
Description: A .NET application failed.
Application: app.exe
Path: C:\path\to\app.exe
Message: You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: C:\path\to\app.exe
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.15' (x64)
.NET location: C:\Program Files\dotnet\

The following frameworks were found:
  1.0.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  1.0.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  1.1.1 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  2.0.0 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  2.2.4 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  2.2.6 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  3.1.22 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  6.0.8 at [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.15&arch=x64&rid=win81-x64
```

Comment: Nothing to do with the SDK, this is about the framework version.  You built the program to target 6.0.15 but only have 6.0.8.  Update required, use the provided link.

Comment: How is my program targeting a specific version though? It just says .NET 6

Comment: @JamesFaix as I wrote in my answer - by default the latest installed SDK is used, your app is build using SDK, SDK has version (which determines the required runtime).

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) framework-dependent apps support only [roll-forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#framework-dependent-apps-roll-forward) runtime selection, so you will need to either install newer runtime version on server or use older SDK to build the app (hence 6.0.8 or earlier). One of the options to force the SDK version ([by default latest installed is used](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version)) for the project is to use [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json).

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run a Web API server on Ubuntu 22.04. First, I installed `dotnet-runtime-7.0` (7.0.8 to be specific). I've got the same error. DLL was compiled with the latest SDK. The same version was installed on server. Nothing.

Later, I noticed that microsoft provide second option:

```
sudo apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-7.0
```

And this solved my problem. Why they cannot print more specific error? Who knows.